# Spaces after <td></td> content in Hotmail

Tags: html, html-email, space, html-table, hotmail

I am designing an e-blast, and when testing it in Hotmail, it adds extra space to the bottom of the content between `<td></td>` tags.

It looks fine in all the other clients.

I have added `display: block; margin:0`

I have also tried to add the following to the head of the email between style tags, but I think Cheetahmail just ignores the CSS.

```
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, 
.ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, 
.ExternalClass div 
{
   line-height: 100%;
} 
table td 
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Does removing the `line-height: 100%;` have any effect?

Comment: No. Hotmail converts line-height to 131%, hence the problem.
I tried this solution: http://www.emailonacid.com/forum/viewthread/43/, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't like <p></p> tags as well as the following piece of code we use to break it into sections:

Comment: <tr>
<td colspan="3" width="720" valign="top" style="padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; text-align:center; background-color:#262626;">
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:15px; color:#e3e3e2; padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; border-right:1px solid #676767;">&nbsp;</p></td>
</tr>

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<font>` tags to style your text. I believe `<span>` also works fine. I find double `<br>` is more consistent than `<p>` tags for spacing.

Add `border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` to your `<table>` tag. You don't need `border:collapse;`

Set all images to `display:block;` unless you are floating them, which is probably not best practice in most cases. Don't need to set `display:block;` for tables.

Also, Gmail ignores any non-inline CSS, so either put it inline or use an inliner tool such as [Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/).